# How to print the whole long page into one page pdf without split many page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print pdf from mtlnovel into one page pdf without split many page.
For example https://www.mtlnovel.com/pick-up-the-invincible-world-attributes-at-the-start/chapter-1-invincible-attribute-system/

for this example page i use [stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html)(chrome addon) to set this css to print whole page into one page pdf without split many page.

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 148.5mm 1891mm;
  }
}
```

but not every chapters of novel is same height size
so i need to manually change height size of every chapter

i am novice so i don't know much can i ask how to automitically change print page height for every chapter.

for example i use [Custom JavaScript for Websites 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk) and this code to get height in mm

```
height = ((document.documentElement.offsetHeight * 0.2733)).toFixed(0);
```

but i don't know how to change css
i want change page heignt to number i got from code above .for example something like this

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 148.5mm heightmm;
  }
}
```

Edit;
Ok now, i try making this and work well for me

```
(function() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      autoresize();
    }
  });
})();

function autoresize() {
  let height = ((document.documentElement.offsetHeight * 0.2733)).toFixed(0);
  var dst2 = document.getElementById("style2");
  if (dst2 != null) {
    document.getElementById("style2").remove();
  }
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.id = 'style2';
  style.innerHTML = '@media print {@page {size: 148.5mm ' + height + 'mm;}}';
  if (document.body != null) {
    document.body.appendChild(style);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this something you are trying to figure out for a website you are working on, or for private use?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this for personal use (not programmatically for visitors to your site), you can use the Chrome devtools to save a fullpage screenshot of a site you are on:

1. Open Chrome Dev Tools on the site in question
2. From the devtools, type `Ctrl + Shift + P` (`Command + Shift + P` on Mac)
3. The command palette will open-- type "screenshot" into it
4. From listed options, select "Capture full size screenshot"

Wait a moment for it to take the full screenshot-- it will show up like a download in that tab when it completes (it won't show up in your actual downloads page, though-- but it *will* drop a file in your downloads destination).  You can then print this file to a PDF however you please.

One caveat-- this won't always work with sites that have some internal scrolling not on the `<body>` element, so in some cases you'll have to futz with the styles to get it right.